# How to stop react-date-picker from setting a default date range?

Tags: javascript, date

This is probably a silly question but I'm going to ask anyway because I haven't seen it yet on stack overflow. Is there a way to get tomorrow's date as a time object?

For instance, I can get today's date with `new Date` but what if I want to get tomorrow's date in the same format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add days to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date)

Comment: @Sysix somewhat but there's not really a selected answer I just figured it out, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

> ```
> const today = new Date()
> // to return the date number(1-31) for the specified date
> console.log("today => ",today)
> let tomorrow =  new Date()
> tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)
> //returns the tomorrow date
> console.log("tomorrow => ",tomorrow)
> ```

[Source](https://www.cloudnweb.dev/2020/08/3-efficient-ways-to-get-tomorrow-date-using-javascript/)